# Configurable products Show "From" next to price in category/product page

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

Magento 1.9 Community. Im trying to show a "From" next to price of configurable products in category/product view page. My template "Milano" has a file list.phtml for categories and i have changed the code to the following :

```
<?php if ($_product->isConfigurable()) { ?>
                        <div style="float:left;"><?php echo $this->__('From ') ?></div><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php } ?>
```

The problem is that the "from" is also visible to configurable products that they don't have different prices. I also used the next code that checks min and max

```
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);
                    $childPriceLowest = "";    
                    $childPriceHighest = "";       
                    foreach($childProducts as $child){
                        $_child = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child->getId());

                        if($childPriceLowest == '' || $childPriceLowest > $_child->getPrice() )
                        $childPriceLowest =  $_child->getPrice();

                        if($childPriceHighest == '' || $childPriceHighest < $_child->getPrice() )
                        $childPriceHighest =  $_child->getPrice();
```

and added a the end the if childpricelowest = childpricehighest then show only price but the page goes white screen.

Perhaps someone can put the together correctly or give another solution?

Comment: If you have a black screen, you certainly have a fatal error. Can you show us the apache logs and magento logs, please ?

Comment: Open index.php and enable developermode() to directly see what's wrong and start debugging from there

Comment: It might be because you iterate through $childProducts and get $child, but you use $_child in the foreach body.

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade your code and testing.
It's work

```
                    <?php if($_product->isConfigurable()) {

                        $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);
                        $childPriceLowest = "";    
                        $childPriceHighest = "";  
                        $priceLowest = Array();

                            foreach ($childProducts as $child): ?>
                                <?php 
                                $_child = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child->getId());

                                if($childPriceLowest == '' || $childPriceLowest > $_child->getPrice() )
                                $childPriceLowest =  $_child->getFinalPrice();
                                $priceLowest[] = $childPriceLowest;

                                if($childPriceHighest == '' || $childPriceHighest < $_child->getPrice() )
                                $childPriceHighest =  $_child->getPrice(); ?>

                            <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php echo '<pre>'; print_r(min($priceLowest)); echo '</pre>'; ?>

                    <?php  }   ?>
```

Print only most lowest price of product's children